# Trying to display longitude and latitude in textViews

Tags: android, android-location

I'm trying to display both the longitude and latitude in seperate textviews after the user presses the get location button. All code seems ok to me but am getting null pointer exceptions. I do not want to do anything when the location is changed only when the user presses the button.

```
package com.seanhannon.fyp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class FYPActivity extends Activity {

public Button getLocation;
public TextView LongCoord;
public TextView LatCoord;
public double longitude;
public double latitude;
public LocationManager lm;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, new MyLocationListener());

    getLocation = (Button)getLocation.findViewById(R.id.GetLocation);
    LongCoord = (TextView)LongCoord.findViewById(R.id.longCoord);
    LatCoord = (TextView)LatCoord.findViewById(R.id.LatCoord);

    getLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {

            showCurrentLocation();
        }



    });

}


protected void showCurrentLocation() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    LongCoord.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
    LatCoord.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
}

}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The XML file is the usual with permissions for fine and coarse location etc.

Here is the Logcat output

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.seanhannon.fyp/com.seanhannon.fyp.FYPActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.seanhannon.fyp.FYPActivity.onCreate(FYPActivity.java:33)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your peace of code

```
getLocation = (Button)getLocation.findViewById(R.id.GetLocation);
LongCoord = (TextView)LongCoord.findViewById(R.id.longCoord);
LatCoord = (TextView)LatCoord.findViewById(R.id.LatCoord);
```

change it with below code

```
getLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GetLocation);
LongCoord = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.longCoord);
LatCoord = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LatCoord);
```

it will remove null pointer exception...

Comment: Thanks a mill, been few months since did any android so basics are gone totally